# Drupal 6 nodereference view, need different view for different roles

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

For one role (slave) The view right now uses the user:uid argument to return the same value as the user that is logged in.  So the user will see a list of options depending on the content they have created.

We have another role (master) that should see a list of options for this selection depending on a different set of rules.  Their list of options should contain all of the created options - without the user:uid argument.

The content type of the node is profile, and the field is a nodereference.  Is there a way to permit the master account to see all of the nodes as a selectable option, and the other to only see the nodes that they have created?

Answer (score 0):

When you are on your view's edit form, you can click 'Add display' to setup multiple displays for your view (pages, blocks, feeds, content panes, attachments).

Once you have created another display you can then go to 'Access' under 'Basic settings' and use the 'Override' button to choose the access rules that you want to apply to your newly created view display.

Overrides can be used on view display's arguments, fields, sorting criteria, filters, etc. This enables one view to control many different displays each of which can have their own unique settings as well as inherit some default settings.

Comment: I didn't have luck with tihs technique.